# Open multiple arranged explorer windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I frequently run a script that takes various files, processes them then places these in other folders. There are 8 relevant folders, may be more in future, and I'd like them all open so I can see what's going on while the script is running (it takes several minutes).

Is there an app, or a way to not only open all these locations, but either have the windows arranged, or have a program display all the locations simply.

Opening all the locations then arranging them manually every time is slow and annoying.

I've googled it, but can only find links to how to open 1 explorer window in a certain location. A second 'desktop' that I could 'open' and 'close' may also work.

How can I do this?

Edit: I need them in separate windows. Open to any applications 'Explorer Replacements' that can do this too.

Comment: Right click Taskbar to arrange all windows options.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a **Library** consisting of the Destination folders:
[image]

Below, files created in **PowerShell** appear in the **Library**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so I need say 8 separate locations to open and all be visible, does this work for that?

Comment: Yes, that's why I displayed the folder path in the Details view, so you could see the view combined items from three different folders. Not sure what the limit is for the number of folders you can have in a library, but I'm sure it's more than eight.

Comment: Oh this pits them all in one folder? I need to see 8 separate windows not combined into 1

Comment: Yes, all in one window. With the information given, I thought that mignt sufficent for monitroing.

Comment: Ah, nice idea but not what I need